# getting rightmost characters in a field in SQL without RIGHT()

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

i'm working on an old AS400 that does not provide support for the SQL RIGHT() function, and i need to SELECT rows based on the X rightmost characters of a number that might be either 7 or 8 characters long using SQL.

How can i get what i want if i cant use RIGHT and i don't know the exact length of the number?.

**here is some context in the off chance it's usefull:**

The number is a date but was stored as a number, so the first zero is stripped away by the database, causing dates starting with zero like 01032016 [read as 01-03-2016] to be trimmed to 1032016).

the database is quite big so requesting all the rows without filtering this field consumes quite a bit of resources and time.

Changing the format of the dates in the database to something more reasonable would cause breaking changes on software I dont maintain and that is mission critial.

Comment: does it support SUBSTRING()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it support modulo?

**Input: 1032016**

```
// Outputs: 2016
YOURDATEASINT % 10000 AS Year

MOD(YOURDATEASINT, 10000) AS Year

// Outputs: 32016
YOURDATEASINT % 1000000 AS MonthYear

MOD(YOURDATEASINT, 1000000) AS MonthYear

// Outputs: 1032016
YOURDATEASINT % 100000000 AS DayMonthYear

MOD(YOURDATEASINT, 100000000) AS DayMonthYear
```

Comment: Hi frumroll, sadly I need to retrieve any part of the date, might be year, year and month or year, month and day.

Comment: You can still use MOD, just change the 10000 as needed. It effectively works the same as RIGHT but only for numbers.

Comment: I ended up using this after all, it provided a better replacement in my use case.

Comment: is there a chance this method is very slow? i'm searching 1.5 million records and it takes 32 seconds for the database to return an answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
SUBSTRING(mystr,character_length(mystr)-x+1,x)
```

or

```
SUBSTRING(mystr,character_length(mystr)-x+1)
```

Comment: It's `character_length' in DB2.

Comment: https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/index.htm?info/db2/rbafzmst02.htm

Comment: You may want to wrap the whole thing in a case structure that makes sure you don't substring more than the length of the field, although this may be unnecessary depending on the column type, length, and other coding considerations.

Comment: Thanks @TracyProbst, generally you are right. In this specific case we know the data is "number that might be either 7 or 8 characters long"

Comment: Sadly character_length() is also not supported :/

Comment: @JoaquinBrandan please try **LENGTH**, in addition, although my solution supply the **RIGHT** functionality I think the arithmetic solutions given here (based on div and mod)  are better for your use-case

Answer (score 3):

If the data was stored as a number, then the DB doesn't strip away the lead digits.  Whatever tool you're using to query the data is doing that.

Assuming the data was stored as a packed or zoned decimal and not integer (very likely), then use `DIGITS()` to convert the number to fixed character including the lead zeros and then you can use `SUBSTR()`

Comment: This ended up being the most straightforward answer answer to my problem, thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

What is striking to me is that the dates, stored as numbers, are not even in YYYYMMDD form. So filtering on a range of these values that spans more than one year is especially annoying.

One thing you can do, if you have authority to create tables and indexes, is create a date table, which simply lists every possible date in some very large range. (150,000 records would cover over 400 years, and is a small table by today's standards.) This table would include several formats, including at least one which is a genuine DATE-type column, and one which is what you are trying to process (in this case, an 8-digit numeric that represents either MMDDYYYY or DDMMYYYY). Then you can use a join to leverage the strength of SQL's query engine, rather than having to perform a function calculation on every row of the data (which is what will have to happen if you transform your data using in-line SQL).

Comment: Thanks for your input but sadly I dont think i have such authority, but i will see if i can get that

The correct formatting in latin speaking languages (argentina in this case) is DD-MM-YYYY as opposed to the YYYY-MM-DD.
You can read more about that here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country

Comment: I'm familiar with all kinds of date formatting, but the usual way to handle various formatting is to convert the "local" format into a more calculation-friendly storage format (true DATE if possible, otherwise YYYYMMDD) at the earliest possible moment on input, and from the storage format to the local format at the latest possible moment on output. Both MMDDYYYY and DDMMYYYY are horrible for calculation. Actually DDMMYYYY is the worst, because you can't even directly specify a range that spans more than one month.

Answer (score 0):

While substring(digits(date_column),x,y) is an option, another option is a combination of the MOD function and dividing.  For example, to get the year, use this: `SELECT MOD(date_column,10000)`, to get the day, use this: `CAST(MOD(date_column,1000000)/10000 AS INT)`, and to get the month, use this: `CAST(date_column/1000000 AS INT)`.